# Looking for Great Example Java Application in MVC or MVP

Tags: java, model-view-controller, orm, tdd, mvp

I'm going to be delivering a presentation to my company regarding MVC, MVP and MVVM patterns, test-driven development, and ORM solutions.  I'm a .Net programmer and have found the NerdDinner application to be a nice example app to illustrate MVC, TDD and ORM.  Is there a good example app in the Java world to demonstrate MVC or MVP with JUnit or other TDD frameworks, and perhaps incorporating Hibernate or another ORM solution?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the samples included in the Spring Framework. Download the [-with dependencies zip](http://www.springsource.com/download/community) and in the sample directory you'll find *Pet Clinic*, an application which uses:

- DAO access with either JDBC, Hibernate or JPA;
- JMX support;
- AspectJ for tracing;
- Validation;
- Spring MVC.

You'll also find three more sample applications which you might find useful.